# How can I capture Heap Dumps for other users?

Tags: debugging, developer-console

Some of my users are experiencing a strange behavior that I can't yet reproduce in a Sandbox, so I'm trying to monitor the bug more closely in our production database.

Since I'm in a production database, I can't edit the code to add new `System.debug()` calls.  Instead, I'd like to use Heap Dumps to inspect the heap and state at various points, but I can't figure out how to collect them.

I'm monitoring a user's debug logs with the `APEX_CODE` filters set to 'Finest'.  Logged in as myself, I have the Developer Console open with 2 heap dump locations set.  But no heap dumps are captured, even though I can see from the debug logs that the code is being run.

How can I capture these dumps, or do you have other recommended debugging techniques?

Comment: Does unchecking 'Show My Current Heap Dumps Only' show Heap Dumps for other users? If not I reckon it may not be possible (reckon this question did come up in the recent Advanced Debugging Webinar, cant remember if it was possible)

Comment: No, doesn't help.

Comment: Hi Benj, Since debug logs are too unpredictable, why dont you store your exceptions in a custom object . In our application we log all exceptions in a custom object. If it is a run time exception and you want to simulate, a quick refresh of the production sandbox might help to recreate the issue. You can also set a flag to debug true on your custom setting and put the logs in a custom object and test it in production as well. Let me know if this helps..

Comment: @buyankumar It's a cool idea, but I don't know how applicable it is here.  We're not having any trouble accessing the debug logs.  The problem is that we haven't planned in advance *WHAT* to monitor or debug, and it doesn't make sense to debug every var at every moment or to deploy new code every time we want to add a debug statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new Tooling API has the `ApexExecutionOverlayAction` object.

> Specifies an Apex code snippet or SOQL query to execute at a specific
>   line of code in an Apex class or trigger and optionally generate a
>   heap dump.

You could use this to capture the heap dump for the required user.

Specifically, try setting:

- `ActionScriptType` to 'None'
- `ExecutableEntityId` to the Apex class Id
- `ExpirationDate` to some time in the future. Maybe an hour out
- `IsDumpingHeap` to true
- `Iteration` to 1
- The `Line` to "The line number of the heap dump marker"
- the `ScopeId` to the required UserId

I hacked something together in a .NET to try it out.

```
SforceService toolingService = // Get an instance of the ToolingService

string apexClassId = "01p70000CLASSID";

// This is the session owners UserId
//string heapUserId = "005700000000FOO";
// This is an Id of another user in the Org
string heapUserId = "005700000000BAR";

int heapDumpLine = 27;

ApexExecutionOverlayAction apexExecutionOverlayAction = new SalesforceTooling.ApexExecutionOverlayAction();
apexExecutionOverlayAction.ActionScriptType = "None";
apexExecutionOverlayAction.ExecutableEntityId = apexClassId;

apexExecutionOverlayAction.IsDumpingHeap = true;
apexExecutionOverlayAction.IsDumpingHeapSpecified = true;

apexExecutionOverlayAction.Iteration = 1;
apexExecutionOverlayAction.IterationSpecified = true;

apexExecutionOverlayAction.Line = heapDumpLine;
apexExecutionOverlayAction.LineSpecified = true;

apexExecutionOverlayAction.ScopeId = heapUserId;

SaveResult[] results = toolingService.create(new sObject[] { apexExecutionOverlayAction });
SaveResult triggerSaveResult = results[0];
if (!triggerSaveResult.success)
{
    Assert.Fail(triggerSaveResult.errors[0].message);
}
Assert.IsTrue(triggerSaveResult.success);
```

Note that this didn't make the Heap Dump Location appear in the developer console for the session owner. I logged in as the target user, but it appears I've broken the developer console for that user:

[image: Broken Salesforce Developer Console - Error loading configuration: Server Error]

However, after hitting the dump point you can pull the resulting dump out from the ToolingService using the ApexLog. E.g.

```
QueryResult apexdumpLogResult = toolingService.query("Select Id, Application, DurationMilliseconds, Location, LogUserId, Operation from ApexLog where Location = 'HeapDump'");
```

Comment: I used the Tooling Rest API via Workbench but followed your process.  Good stuff!